# npm run build takes to long in django+react app

Tags: reactjs, django, npm, django-react

recently i moved to react and i am quite familiar with it , now i started using react with backend django, after i set up it was all working but ,every time i change code and i want to see it , i need to **npm run build** , although this works but on real world projects where maybe 100s of js file , run build is gonna take hours to build , and i cant wait that long to do changes and it is very impractical.like **python manage.py runserver** makes instant easy updation , can you give me solution for this...

Comment: Have you setup your React project using `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run the front end with `npm start` or `yarn start` depending on your preference from the front-end directory and do live updates that way. Then you can save the actual build for when you've completed the front end. You don't even have to worry about running the django runserver command unless you have data on the backend you're collecting. In that case just run both until you want to build the final product.